# How do I write a TreeNode to a PrintStream of a given File?

Tags: java, string, file, treenode, printstream

I have to write a method

```
write(Printstream p)
```

where `p` has been defined as

```
new PrintStream(new File(QUESTION_FILE).
```

I don't even really need to know how to go directly from a `TreeNode` into the `PrintStream`, just mainly how to put Strings line by line into it.

Comment: Did you look at the spec for PrintStream?

Answer (score 0):

> how to put Strings line by line into it

Well, it's quite straightforward when [looking at the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html):

```
p.println("This is your line");
p.println("New line (OS dependant) is added automatically");
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as TreeNode has implemented (overridden) the toString() method, you can just do this:

```
p.print(this);
```

The other way of doing it would be to implement a recursive version:

```
p.println(myvalue);
for (TreeNode child : children) {
    write(child);
}
```